# When using Swift Package Manager how can I generate an Xcode project file for development

Tags: xcode, swift, package-managers, swift-package-manager

I am using the new open source Swift Package Manager and am able to download the files.
I want the manager to create a "development environment" (Through Xcode) based on the packages it retrieved.

Has anybody dealt with this?

Comment: Reading the [documentation overview](https://swift.org/package-manager/#conceptual-overview) shows that what you are asking for is not a feature of the Package Manager. There's nothing about it either in the [Community Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageManagerCommunityProposal.md).

Comment: What you mean "development environment" ?

Comment: @EricD: As of recently it now is a feature of the SPM! \o/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Update: as mentioned in other answers, you can now generate Xcode project files with this command:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

---

#### Original answer:

The Swift Package Manger (SPM) is cross platform, It works on Mac and Linux.
The Xcode is Mac OS only, so I don't think SPM will be hard integrate to work with Xcode.

SPM can do 2 things:

- Build swift source code into modules (Executable and Library)
- Fetch dependencies (from git or local path)

The SPM work only with Source code, folders and files. It doesn't know anything about Xcode.
Also it is mentioned that in the future Apple plans to add support for other languages not only Swift and Objc.

My answer: SPM will not ingrate with Xcode. But because it's open-source anyone can just make its own fork and add custom feature that would generate Xcode specific files.

Comment: This answer is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386908/560648)

Answer (score 40):

Update (2021/05/23):

With Xcode having gained official support for Swift Packages the recommended way to create packages these days is from within Xcode via "*Xcode > File > New > Swift Package*".

---

Update (2020/11/20):

With [PR 3062](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/3062) merged `generate-xcodeproj` will soon be marked as deprecated.

---

Original answer:

As of [PR #174](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/174) on the [swift-package-manager](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/) project, there exists an option for generating an Xcode project file in root directory of the package:

```
$ swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

Note: Earlier builds used:

```
$ swift build --generate-xcodeproj
```

It will officially be part of Swift's 3.0 release.
But it is already available with [`Xcode Swift DEVELOPMENT Snapshot 2016-03-24`](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots) or later!

Comment: @RyanCollins: thanks, updated. There's really no need to downvote correct, yet newly outdated answers. Just write a comment (as you did) asking for an update edit.

Comment: This answer is currently being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386908/8239061).

Comment: @Regexident do you have any idea what's going to replace `swift package generate-xcodeproj`? Or should we just start projects directly from Xcode and integrate the Swift PM from there?

Comment: With "Xcode > File > New > Swift Package" being available from Xcode I don't see Apple providing a replacement for `swift package generate-xcodeproj`. They simply needed the latter as a temporary workaround until the feature made it into Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do now, if you had Xcode 11 installed is just run this command and xcode-tools will automatically open the appropriate `Package.swift` and resolve as an project for you to open in Xcode:

```
$ xed .
```

---

**Pre 2020:**

I wrote a small command line tool for that

it's called `spawn`: https://github.com/vinhnx/spawn

Basically, it's just a small combination of repetitive commands when you want to try out a SPM package:

```sh
$ swift package update # update or resolve package dependencies
$ swift package generate-xcodeproj # generate a .xcodeproj to edit on Xcode
$ xed . # open generated .xcodeproj automatically
```

Comment: In case you only see the package (non-expandable) in the project navigator, try to restart Xcode